# How to get a string inside of data-cfemail tag by php regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I want to get `344747585151010c745359555d581a575b59` from the string.

```
[a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="344747585151010c745359555d581a575b59"]
```

I'm tried the following PHP to capture it:

```
preg_match_all("/<a [^>]*data-cfemail=\"?([^\">]+)\"?>/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have less than or greater than symbols in your string. Try:

```
data-cfemail="?([^"\]]+)(?:"|])
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/JoImnS/2/

Note, this regex is looser than it could be. I assumed the double quotes encapsulating the `data-cfemail` were optional, if not this can be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a **[positive look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** on the `data-cfemail`, and then simply match any digit or lowercase letter that comes directly after that:

`/(?<=data-cfemail=")[\da-z]+/`

Breaking this down:

- `(?<=data-cfemail=")` - match anything that follows `data-cfemail="`
- `[\da-z]` - match any digit or lowercase letter
- `+` - match one or more of the digits / lowercase letters

`preg_match("/(?<=data-cfemail=")[\da-z]+/", $input_line, $output_array);`

Returns:

```
array(1
  0 => 344747585151010c745359555d581a575b59
)
```

This can be seen working on PHPLiveRegex **[here](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oAm)**.